Allow high-rep community members to help review No Longer Needed comment flags
TL;DR Please, allow very-high rep users (50,000 rep on "full" rep levels, 10,000 rep on "beta" rep levels, and 5,000 rep on "private beta" rep levels) to help review No Longer Needed comment flags.
I'd imagine this could work by adding it as another review queue, where the comments are sent to after they are flagged. It would require 2 net votes to delete from high-rep users in order to actually be deleted (and leaving the queue at -2 net votes to delete). In order to prevent problems, users could not review comments if they flagged the comment, commented on the post, or made the post. Perhaps, in order to help get rid of other useless comments, it could show all the comments under that post.
No Longer Needed comment flags are used to flag comments that are, as the name would suggest, not useful. These types of comments flags tend to be pretty easy and obvious (not just my opinion here, this seems to also be the general moderator consensus), and yet only moderators can deal with them (unless it happens to be nuked by enough regular flags, which only happens 0.1% of the time). On Stack Overflow alone, in 2022, 243,198 comment flags were handled by moderators. That's nearly as much as how many flags on actual posts were handled my moderators in the same time. In 2021, that number was 403,458, significantly more than post flags. Based on this data, about 71% of those were No Longer Needed (NLN) flags. So, the Stack Overflow mods alone handled an estimated 172,671 NLN flags in 2022 and 286,455 in 2021, which could have easily been handled by the community, comments which I would imagine very rarely require anything other than a quick deletion.
As of right now, I'm not suggesting the handling of Unfriendly/Unkind, Harassment, Bigotry, or Abuse, or Something Else comment flags as those are much more likely to more difficult to handle and/or require moderator intervention. The numbers 50k/10k/5k and the 2/-2 are just ideas of number that seem roughly correct, I'm not particularly attached to the numbers here. The 2 votes to delete comes from the fact that it currently take 3 flags to nuke comments, and 2 more user (plus the original flagger) reaches that 3.
Yes, on certain sites, this review queue might get backlogged. But let's say that only 10% of NLN flags are handled by high-rep users because there are very few queue reviewers, and most still have to be handled by mods. That's still tens of thousands of flags on SO alone per year that mods now didn't have to handle. That's still a major improvement.
Yes, I'm aware of these other proposals for comment moderation, but I think that mine is significantly different and address some of the concerns brought up there. Yes, I'm aware that some of the smaller sites will not have 2 eligible non-mod users to do this (however those also tend to be sites with much less comments to moderate). I think that the queue should probably be turned of though for sites only 1 eligible non-mod user, as they would just be wasting their time. I think that we should probably make this an opt-in feature to also avoid the sites where there isn't really an existing comment moderation problem and/or there are very few users who could even review in it. I also think this should not be add on MSE and per-site metas, per the answer below. Yes, I'm aware that sometimes high-rep users make mistakes. However, we let users with much lower rep than this delete with only 3 votes actual posts, which are much more important than comments, and that mostly works out well. The chances of the original flagger, and 2 very high-rep users all wrongly thinking a comment should be deleted are rather low. Something similar to this already exists for chat moderation, and that also generally works out fine.
Sorry this question is so long, but there's a lot to say.
So, please, let the community handle these, and take a burden off of our moderators, and let them focus their time on the things that truly require a moderator.

If you are suggesting two net votes to "remove" a comment then you are suggesting that potentially three very high rep users will have to view the comment (or set of comments). If, as you say (and in general I agree with you), most of these comments are pretty easy and obvious, then why not just let ONE very high rep user on their own have the ability to REMOVE the comment or SKIP but not DECLINE. In this way, the easiest comments are quickly removed leaving the more difficult ones for the mods. I see no reason to make this a consensus vote.

While I'm generally opposed to SO only features, I wonder how much more/less of an issue this is elsewhere - it might be a good idea to consider this as an opt in, rather than default or opt out feature

@JourneymanGeek I do think this could be useful on a bunch of non-SO sites, but yes I do think it should be opt in. Added to the question.

@PeterJames do you really trust every high rep user to have unilateral nuking power? I don't.

tbf, as a mod sometimes I don't trust myself to have unlateral nuking power :D

I have flagged literally thousands of comments as No Longer Needed and I have probably read three or four times as many, both here and elsewhere. As many people have said here before, comments are second class citizens here and should not really hang around too long. It seems people trust me to get them right when I am flagging, so all the more reason to trust a very high rep user to handle my flags. If you want, restrict very high rep users to dealing with comments raised by people who have the Marshall badge.

The problem is robo-reviewers....@PeterJames

Yes, robo-reviewers. They are a problem. You can still have audits. If a robo-reviewer clicked REMOVE on a comment that should be SKIPPED then they would fail the audit. And everything a reviewer does is visible anyway from their activity profile.

@PeterJames and yet we still have robo-reviewers. I have personally seen multiple users who have multiple steward badges and are 6 digit rep and yet clearly robo-review. There is always a (small) random chance that the reviewer is incorrect, so there could be 2.
I think it's a much better idea to start with 2 reviewers and if the queue is really backlogged and the reviews are very accurate then maybe trying 1. Do you disagree?@PeterJames

Rep doesn't mean they know what they're doing. I would support what I've personally called "mini-mods" as long as the privilege is linked to action. 100k or even a million rep does NOT make that user a good curator. Thousands of helpful comment flags would be a far better indicator imo

@Zoe-Savethedatadump yes, I know. I think its much easier and much more likely to be implemented something that roughly is similar to our current system for other things.
Fact is, the review queues assume that it is pretty unlikely that multiple high rep users will all be wrong. Is that true? Usually. But I do generally think the review queues are a net benefit.

We kinda already can. A few flags on a NLN comment already auto-deletes them.

@KevinB Yes, but is it very rare (only 0.1% of cases) because its pretty unlikely that 3 users will happen to randomly look at the comments of a random post and all decide to flag the same comment.

@Starship Yes, however, it's just a matter of tooling. For example, we already have /tools where we can find posts with a lot of comments, or posts getting a ton of views, etc, a similar view that showed posts with NLN comments would suffice.

@KevinB Do you think that as many people use/know about /tools as they do review quques?

@Starship I don't, and i think that's a good thing. I'd rather it be something people who understand SO to the point that they even know that area exists use it, as opposed to people stumbling into the review queues from the red dot in the header.

@KevinB Okay, but what about the potential problem of virtually no one actually reviews the comments (and hence 3 flags is very hard to get)

In most cases... it just doesn't matter. it's not super important that old no longer needed comments get handled quickly.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@TylerH hopefully some of them area. After all, people do use the current review queues.

@Starship Moved my thoughts (and greatly expanded on them) to an answer

@Starship regarding Kevin's suggestion of /tools, it is by design that far fewer people are aware of that page because far fewer people have access to that page in the first place. You get access to the first review queue at, what, 500 reputation? You don't get access to the /tools page until 10,000 reputation. There's a huge number of people between 500 rep and 10,000 reputation on Stack Overflow, for example

@TylerH No, the reason people are aware of review queues is because they see this red  dot and wonder what is.

I don't see how that addresses anything I said. I didn't mention anything about how discoverable the review queues are. You don't see a red dot until you have access to at least one queue, anyway.

@TylerH that's my point. People use/know about the queues because of the red dot drawing their attention.

If this happens, Meta (MSE, MSO, maybe all per-site Metas) should be excluded
Especially on controversial and/or poorly-received posts, even high rep users can and do leave unnecessary comments. These can be negative comments, directed toward SE, Inc. about <insert a change here>. Considering the sentiment can be popular, regardless of the value of the comment, I think comments on Meta (particularly MSO/MSE) should be handled by diamond users (mods, some SE, Inc. staff).

Yeah, from the mod end, the biggest learning curve after my appointment has definitely been comment moderation. Meta's very unique in how comments are handled, and a lot of discretion goes into handling even NLN flags sometimes. I agree that Meta should be excluded.

Yes, I think I agree with this one. Do you think I should add it to the original post or not?

When handling comment flags, it’s often useful to see the full context.  This usually requires looking at all the comments on a post — including deleted comments.
If non-moderator reviewers are trying to review NLN comments flags without the full context, this could be problematic.
And I really don’t think non-moderators should be given the ability to see comments that have been deleted.

I didn’t suggest they be able to see deleted comments and I suggested they see all the comments on that post when reviewing (perhaps, now that I think of it, with the specific one they are reviewing highlighted)

Why is the full context needed to review NLN flags? The decision to delete a comment should be based on what is visible to all users. If a comment does not make sense due to deleted context, then that comment should be deleted too.

I have some doubts
I'm not sure users at these rep levels, at least on Stack Overflow where it's certainly the biggest issue by orders of magnitude, are all that interested in curation/moderation. I don't have hard numbers, obviously, but I think the majority of users over 50,000 reputation are mostly interested in answering questions (because it takes a lot of time and effort to get to that amount of reputation and if you spend that time doing curation tasks, you aren't earning that kind of reputation). We already have an issue with high reputation users not voting to close questions that ought to be closed... I don't see them reviewing comments when they already won't close a duplicate question they've answered a dozen times before.
Also, all users can already sort of participate in this--comments flagged NLN auto-delete if they receive 3 such flags from users. I think it would be better if such a review queue just placed comments with NLN flags on them in a pile and let reviewers cast their own NLN flags on comments if they think the comment is truly not needed, rather than introduce some new "comment delete vote" that doesn't yet exist in the system software.
I think there's a better way
Finally, and more importantly, I think there's a better way to improve this without introducing yet another reputation-gated privilege. Catija, before her exit, was trying to spearhead an initiative to rework privileges to be less tied to reputation levels, and this would be a step in the opposite (read: wrong) direction, I think. Users with such high amounts of reputation are not necessarily experts at curation, just experts at whatever subjects they are writing answers for.
Instead, I think a system that augments the existing auto-deletion process would be better, where users with certain numbers of helpful flags have their NLN flag weight raised to count as additional flags (on comments where you don't have any comments of your own). Something like:



Helpful flag count
NLN flag weight




0 to 499
1 flag


500 to 999
2 flags


1000+
3 flags (equivalent to auto-delete)



Furthermore, any declined flags could temporarily reduce the flag weight back down to 1 even if you have 10k+ helpful flags. For example, if your flag history is such that you would see a "some of your flags were recently declined" notice, your NLN flags would only count as one.
This augmentation could exist as a standalone change, or as both a change to the system and in the form of a review queue for users with access to it (based on helpful flag count).
N.B. numbers give above are based on my recollection of auto-deletion for NLN being 3 NLN flags... if it is 4, I would obviously adjust those example numbers to match. Also, the helpful flag thresholds for increased flag weights would need to change for beta sites, of course.
Also, I think the thresholds for increased flag weight that I suggested are a bit low, but I was worried about personal bias skewing what I thought was reasonable (I have nearly 30,000 helpful flags on SO alone, and >20k of them are comment flags)

I am suggesting that it lets them just flag the comments (and/or click recommend deletion which will then cast the flag).  Yes, some high-rep users are interested in reviewing, but plenty are (how the review queues work). I personally have more than 1k helpful flags on SO (and nearly 1k helpful NLN flags even) and I don't trust myself with comment nuking power. Also, sometimes flags are declined by mistake, when they shouldn't be, through a misclick, etc. You shouldn't have to work back 500-1000 because a mod misclicked.

@Starship There's no review queue for users with 50,000 reputation. The highest reputation threshold for a proper review queue (rather than just the 10K tools page) we have on Stack Overflow is 3,000 reputation. That's a big gap.

I know that. But even user with 3,000 has put in a lot of effort to make posts. And yet they review. Why wouldn't this logic extend. SO has user with 7 digit rep who are mods (and hence obviously do moderation tasks).

@Starship Re: "work back 500-1000 because a mod misclicked", I think you misunderstood my suggestion. The flag weight reduction due to a declined flag would only apply while the 'recently declined warning' is active... that only lasts 7 days, at minimum (or longer if you keep casting new flags that continue to get declined). The point is a design that slows users down when they've recently "made a mistake". It's only temporary.

@Starship Yes, there are some users who review at high rep, sure. But not many. Users who opt to become moderators are exceptions (no pun intended to the exception handlers).

Also, I don't think 3,000 reputation is really a lot of effort, at least not compared to 50,000 reputation. Heck, you can get to 2,000 reputation just from suggested edits alone. You really can't compare the two in similar lights. I don't recall how long it took me to get to 3,000 reputation, but it wasn't long. I've been a member on SO for over a decade and I'm still not even to 25k reputation. There are some users who get to 50k in a year, sure, but that just underscores my point: they aren't spending their time reviewing things; they're spending it answering.

Okay maybe that's a reasonable idea then. Honestly, this seems like it would be better as a different feature requests though. I can't speak for SO very much, but for my "home" stack, Space SE, that's not the case. 5 of the 7 top reviewers of close votes, for example, are above my suggested threshold.
If the reviews are really accurate and the queue isn't really get reviewed, I would be open to decreasing the rep requirement.

Once somebody got the maximum flag weight and they only flagged as NLN, they would never have anything declined. Perhaps, once after reaching 1000 helpful flags (with a low decline rate, of course) a user would be allowed an increasing number of auto-delete flags per day. Say 10 auto-delete flags per day at 1000 helpful flags, 20 auto-delete flags per day at 2000 helpful flags and so on. The user would have to tick a checkbox when flagging to select auto-delete.

@PeterJames That's a good point, a small amount of the extra weighted flags per day or some similar mechanism would probably be good, barring some other mechanism to ensure we avoid abuse from that avenue.

I am in favour of better systems to remove comments, once they have served their purpose. Comments are second-class citizens here, especially comments that can be flagged as No Longer Needed.
However the only real benefit, imho, of implementing a system of allowing high rep (or very high rep) users to handle No Longer Needed comments, as far as I can see from your question, is to reduce the workload of moderators.
From the point of view of a flagger, there will be no real benefit. It is not a benefit for a flagger for their NLN comment flags to be handled more quickly. There is no limit on the number of flags sitting in the mod flag queue (correct me if I am wrong) so a patient flagger will eventually have all their flags handled. I see no problem in waiting two or even three weeks for a flag to be handled. If anything, the extra time gives me a chance to retract the flag if I review the flag myself and change my mind (it's happened).
It is a bigger risk for a flagger for their flags to be regularly declined. Your proposal will expose me (as say, a relatively experienced NLN comment flagger) to having my flags decided upon by several very high rep users who may have very little idea or experience of how to handle NLN comment flags. In addition, very high rep users may not have access to all the tools that mods have to review the comment history that might be needed, and they probably don't have access to chat with the other mods in a secure mod-only chat room.

I can only imagine that the decline rate will increase if very high rep users are able to decline flags as well as mark them as helpful.

At the moment, I have a very high level of confidence that the mods handling my flags know what they are doing. This is very important from the point of view of a NLN comment flagger. Why? Because if more than two comments in a thread are flagged, then we must have confidence that the mod handling the flags will quickly see what we saw and then agree with us. With a NLN comment flag, there is no opportunity to explain what we saw.
(As an aside, I once used to add a comment under posts explaining what I was flagging as NLN and why and then after the flag was handled I would delete my own comment. However, a mod asked me to stop that habit explaining that it was neither needed nor really useful)
So, if I am not confident that the very high rep users handling my NLN comment flags will see what I saw, then I will have to start raising custom moderator flags or raising a flag on the post itself so that I can add an explanation. Or stop flagging.
If I suspected that robo-reviewers were handling my NLN comment flags, then I would definitely stop flagging. Even the thought that a robo-reviewer could be handling my flags is disconcerting.
If, as I suspect, the decline rate increases for NLN comment flags then I can imagine that the mods themselves may have more work (rather than less) because:

some flags that used to be NLN would be raised as custom flags in the future
some flaggers will ask why their flags were declined


As an aside, you mentioned that only 0.1% of comments are nuked by regular flags. it would be nice to know which comments have been flagged by other users as NLN, for example the outline flag in the image below:

This would be similar to the information available to us about Close flags for posts.

This seems to put far too much of an importance on comments. Posts can be deleted by regular (high rep) users and that functionality is exposed almost freely to users. Users who can delete posts can see how many del-votes there currently are on a post and can find posts with delete votes in the 10k tools section. The concerns here are way stricter than what we currently do for first-class citizen (posts) deletion. I guess the difference is that deleted comments can't also be reviewed by regular users, deleted posts can. However, it still seems like over-protection for comments.

OK, also granted, the 10k tools suck to use. So, you could go find some posts to delete or...you could just go do something else instead. But the option is still there. Still, there is tooling around discovery of deletable posts. SOCVR accepts del-pls requests to coordinate deletions that will otherwise most likely never happen. There is also Natty, the bot which monitors for new answers to old questions and brings them up to review and potential deletion if they are NAA or not needed.

There is also a bot which reports suspected rude comments for review and often enough results in comments flag nuked for U/U. It doesn't find a lot such comments (only monitors incoming ones and has fairly high standard for what might be rude) and a fair bit are false positives (e.g., it matches comments like "this is spam" which aren't rude). But the bot does still allow users to review comments and flag to delete ones that shouldn't be there. BTW, some are not rude but still unneeded and end up flagged NLN. So, there is already some effort for coordinated comments cleanup.

@VLAZ Hmm, I hope my answer does not imply that I want comments to hang around. I am all for removing as many of them as reasonably possible. My main issue with this proposal is to make sure that any changes won't have a negative impact on the decline rate.

It's simple to reduce the decline rate - don't allow non-mods to decline. If they simply not confirm, then it'd be up to a mod to decline. Also consider that the "review" can be done almost entirely of existing tools. Expose comments with NLN flags somewhere (similar to how posts with del-votes are exposed) and allow users to cast further flags. Or not cast any.

@VLAZ Yes, I agree, don't allow non-mods to decline. I made that point (albeit verbosely) in my first comment below the question.

@PeterJames the chances of 2 very high rep users both being wrong is…low enough for dealing with second class citizens. We allow 3 users with much lower rep to delete posts, which are actuallly much more important. I think knowing what comments were flagged by other users could invite people getting upset someone flagged their comment (having a reasonable idea who it was) and being rude. I do think non mods should be able to decline, just as nonmods can decline post flags (again, much more important)

@Starship I see what you are saying. Most of my NLN comment flags are on old posts. Some of them well over a year old, so I don't really think that anybody is going to get upset by their comments being deleted really, especially as the comments I flag are often connected to edits being asked for and confirmation that they were made, and similar. I don't see a problem with other users (who have gained the privilege) seeing my NLN flags.

@PeterJames yes, same here, but that's not all NLN flags...I agree it would be much better if it was a privilege rather than for everyone. But at this point were totally of topic of this feature requests, no?

I'd rather there be a queue per comment flag type for people who have raised a certain number (based on how frequently that type of flag is raised) of that comment flag type and maintain a certain helpful-flag-percentage of the last N of those flags which were handled by mods. Just because you know how to raise/handle a certain type of comment flag doesn't mean you know how to do the others. I am and was a pretty heavy flagger of NLN comments way before I reached my current rep level on SO. Having rep has little to no correlation with ability to properly moderate comments.
That, and/or the deputy/comment-mods idea.
